# Враг (ворог) и ворожба

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Здравствуйте!
Как вы думаете, могут ли быть родственными слова "Ворог" (враг) и "ворожба"? Или они просто похоже звучат, а общего между ними ничего нет?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По одной версии это, действительно, однокоренные слова. Слово "враг" заимствовано из ст.-сл. языка, где врагъ - это общеславянское vorgъ, того же корня, что и др.-пр. wargs - злой и лат. urgere  угнетать, гнать. Слово "ворожить" также образовано от vorgъ, тогда ворожить - это вредить, причинять зло.

Однако существует версия, согласно которой  "ворожить" происходит от слова "ворожа" - жребий, известного в др.-рус. языке и в диалектах. Тогда ворожить - это бросать жребий (без колдовства).

Answer (score 0):

В санскрите есть слово «враджья» - враг, и сегодня мало кто будет оспаривать тот факт, что многие слова в славянских и европейских языках имеют санскритские корни. Также есть «врана» - рана, «вранин» - раненный и т.д. Поэтому, считаю, что «враг» пришёл из этого древнейшего на земле языка в русский, а вот «ворожба»… Это не только жребий, гадание, порча, приворот, но и врачевание.  Давайте разберёмся, что такое магия и колдовство, т.к. с этими понятиями  ворожба связана непосредственно. И так, магия – воздействие человека на скрытые силы природы посредством развитой воли. Маг, колдун, знахарка, ворожея по-рож-дают определённые мыслеформы, способные влиять на окружающий мир. «Рожать», значит – производить.  В связи с этим, я считаю, что ворожбе ближе рождение, нежели враг и вражда, а корень «рож» является основой этого слова.